# Semantic question regarding functions of operators

Tags: functions, hilbert-spaces

If I have a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$, then I can examine operators $A:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$.

$\ $

I can also examine functions $f$ of operators $A \mapsto f(A)$.

$\ $

Is there a technical name for the space (let's say $\mathcal{V}$) of all operators on $\mathcal{H}$? (so I could write $f:\mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{V}$)

Comment: Would $\mathcal{H}^{\mathcal{H}}$ work for what you are doing?  The functional programmer in me wants to say $ f : (\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H})$

Comment: Are your $A$s linear?

Comment: Yes my A's are linear, I should have mentioned